# Variable sticking around throughout while loop in C++

Tags: c++, c

I'm migrating from C# to C++, and I've come across an issue of scope that doesn't seem to make sense. Here's some example code that shows my issue.

```
int rounds = 0;
char *names[10];
while (rounds < 10)
{
  char name[10];
  if (rounds == 1)
    std::strcpy(name, "Test");

  std::cout << &name << " " << name << std::endl;

  names[rounds] = name;

  ++rounds;
}
```

I don't understand why I keep getting the same address, and why the variable comes around already set after the second round.

To explain what I was doing when I came across this. I was trying to do up an unordered map with name keys and answer values. What I think should happen is that char name[10] should create a fresh variable each time the while loops. But instead, I'm getting the exact same string literal, and the second round would wipe the first name away with the second name.

I understand that string literals are archaic and this isn't a problem with c++ strings. I've also solved the problem by using something like:

```
char *name = new char[10];
```

But I'm really curious why the aforementioned code ends up with the same array address every time. Is that some sort of compiler optimization, or am I understanding scope wrong?

**Edit:** I believe I've refined what it is I'm actually looking for. This example might not be the best for the question I need answered.

What I'm looking for is the correct way to create a list (be it an array or otherwise) of pointers to objects created during a loop. If possible, a C and a C++ implementation would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't initialised the variable to anything - so printing it is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 3):

The local variable is likely to pitch up at the same memory address on the stack each time round the loop, and since you don't initialise it it will still contain whatever was there before.

Initialising it will demonstrate this:

```
int rounds = 0;
char *names[10];
while (rounds < 10)
{
    char name[10] = ""; //<--- this here
    if (rounds == 1)
        std::strcpy(name, "Test");

    std::cout << &name << " " << name << std::endl;

    names[rounds] = name;

    ++rounds;
}
```

Comment: So in my real world example, where the first value was being written over on successive loops, is that just a side effect of happening across the same address each time, or is it intentionally keeping the variable?

Comment: Definitely a side effect

Answer (score 2):

You are using a *stack* variable, name, that's one of the most useful features of C/C++ over managed languages since it doesn't require an heap allocation and is inherently reentrant.

Stack variables have as scope from the declaration to the next closing block ( } ), so if you want to use it inside a loop you have to initialise it for every iteration.

So your code has a problem, you initialise it at the second iteration and not at the first one.

The fact the *address* of the variable is always the same is correct since for every iteration the compiler reserve the same 10 bytes on the stack for it. (Depending on the processor/OS the compiler may reserve more than 10 bytes)

Comment: Technically they assign to it in the second iteration of the loop.  Initialization only happens at the point of declaration.

Comment: Sorry. Not assigning to it the first time was just as a, "yep, nothing here because we haven't touched it" sanity check.

Comment: I'd really like to hear more about this difference between C and managed languages.

Answer (score 0):

```
int rounds = 0;
char *names[10];
while (rounds < 10)
{
```

At this point, `name` does not exist.

Here you instantiate a fresh `name` with uninitialized contents. This happens on every loop iteration.

```
  char name[10];
```

Here you initialize the fresh buffer if it's the first round:

```
  if (rounds == 1)
    std::strcpy(name, "Test");
```

At this point, the buffer's contents are uninitialized in rounds 2 onwards.

The address of `name` is implementation-specific and is not guaranteed to be anything in particular. That it happens to be the same on each loop iteration is certainly nice, but you don't need to pay any attention to that because there's nothing in the semantics of C++ that would tell you what to expect.

The line below invokes undefined behavior in rounds 2 onwards when you attempt to use the contents of `name`:

```
  //                           vvvvvvv- undefined behavior
  std::cout << &name << " " << name << std::endl;
```

Here you store the address of `name`:

```
  names[rounds] = name;

  ++rounds;
```

At the moment the closing brace is reached, the scope of `name` ends. The object is destroyed and ceases to exist. The address of `name` that you've stored above is a dangling pointer, since the `name` instance has been destroyed now.

It is a pure coincidence that the next time `name` is intantiated above, it happens at the same address and you get some usable data there. It could also format your hard drive, so be careful: Undefined behavior literally means that the code is free to do anything.

```
}
```

In any case, your code is some very weird mix of C and C++ paradigms. When you write C++, last thing you want to see is naked arrays of `char` and the use of C string API.

Had you written your code in idiomatic C++ instead, it would read almost the same as it would in C#. And the wonderful thing is that this code has no overhead compared to the C version, but has all the safety-by-construction that you can't get from C (because C is not C++!).

```
int main() {
   std::vector<std::string> names;
   const int N = 10;
   names.reserve(N); // optional to prevent the vector from reallocating as it grows
   std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(names), N, +[]{ return "Test"; });
   for (auto const & name : names)
      std::cout << name << std::endl;
}
```

If you insist on writing the code using the C string APIs - for absolutely no reason, since it has no performance advantage over C++ used properly - here you go:

```
int main() {
   const int N = 10;
   char *names[N];
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i ++)
      names[i] = strdup("Test");
   for (auto name : names)
      std::cout << (void*)name << " " << name << std::endl;
}
```

Here, each address stored in `names` will be different, as `strdup` allocates a fresh string. Output:

```
0x7fce7b700000 Test
0x7fce7b700010 Test
0x7fce7b700020 Test
0x7fce7b700030 Test
0x7fce7b700040 Test
0x7fce7b700050 Test
0x7fce7b700060 Test
0x7fce7b700070 Test
0x7fce7b700080 Test
0x7fce7b700090 Test
```

You could also do:

```
int main() {
   char *names[10];
   std::generate(std::begin(names), std::end(names), +[]{ return strdup("Test"); });
   for (auto name : names)
      std::cout << (void*)name << " " << name << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Glad to know I'm just as confused as I think I am XD

I think a key that I'm looking for is this:
What would be the correct C way to create a series of elements? looping, make a thing, put it in a thing, have a collection of things at the end. That seems to be the actually useful consequence that I'm missing right now.

Comment: You asked a C++ question. If you want to ask a C question, please do so: as a separate question. Because C isn't some subset of C++, they are entirely different programming languages. If you're writing C++, you're not supposed to think like you would in C - your code will be horrible.

Comment: I'm working on some very old code that is much more C than C++, so it's best that I know the most bare bones implementation of things.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're entirely correct. Can this be moved?

Comment: Fix it as you go through it. Obviously your old code is broken, there's no point in keeping it designed so that it can keep being broken. It's very, very easy to write broken C code if you're used to C#. Leverage C++ to do what you need done - safely. Leverage the compiler to manage resources for you. That's what C++ is there for, and that's how it majorly differs from most other languages. RAII is a core language feature, and it doesn't exist in C#, Java, etc.